# Installing a journal given package?

Tags: packages

I wish to submit a paper of mine to a journal that gives a package to be used for submission preparation.

However, when I used it I got the error message "File `dm.sty' not found". How to solve this problem?

The original page is http://demmath.mini.pw.edu.pl/tech_req.html

Comment: Which journal is it? Don't they have it available somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I slightly modify the example they give to post it here. It is  a math. journal.

Comment: *A* math journal, or *the* math journal?

Comment: there is no `dm` package at ctan.  unless we know where to find this package, no one can help.  identifying the journal is the only clue that might provide the necessary information.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks so much. The page is http://demmath.mini.pw.edu.pl/tech_req.html

Comment: @Werner: Thanks so much. The page is http://demmath.mini.pw.edu.pl/tech_req.html

Comment: @YLChou, download the `dm.sty` linked to at that page and save it in the same directory as your `.tex` file for this paper. Optionally, if you plan to write more than one paper for this journal, you can follow the directions at [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

Comment: @PaulGessler: Write this up with a link to [`dm.sty`](http://demmath.mini.pw.edu.pl/dm.sty), for what it's worth...

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks very much. It works now! But I got the error message "\@thehead ... 0 = \pstr \phead \else \rightheadline"? What is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original question has been answered already, the remaining error has its origins in a missing `\maketitle` and `\keywords` and `\subjclass` statements. They are desperately needed as page heading styles.

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{dm}

\begin{document}

\title{Theory on Brontosaurs}

\author[A. Elk]{Ann Elk (Misses)}
\address{Brontosaurs excavation institute}
\email{ann@brontosaurs.net}


\keywords{brontosaurs, elks}
\subjclass{Primary brontosaurs; Secondary dinosaurs.}


\maketitle

\section{First section}



\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{0}

\bibitem[Elk]{}  R. Hill and A. Dow,
\emph{Another Theory on Brontosaurs},
Journal of Dinosaurs. 1 (2015), 1--4000.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Indeed, still I got error message even using what is given. Now I get this "error loading `name of the file'.pdf"?

Comment: Is this problem caused by my Miktex setting?

Comment: @YLChou: I can't explain such an error as there is principally no `.pdf` file loaded in my example. You must provide more information

Comment: *Could I just say, Christian, for one moment that she has a new theory about the brontosaurus? Yes my word you may well ask what it is, this theory of hers. Well, this theory that she has - that is to say, which is hers - is hers: **The Theory** by A. Elk brackets Miss brackets.* `:)`

Comment: @YLChou: I don't use MikTeX therefore I have no idea actually, but I guess, that MikTeX settings are not the cause of the 'described' problem